# How to rewrite this short algorithm to make it more efficient?

Tags: algorithm, function, loops, statistics, coding-efficiency

Any way to write a function that is functionally equivalent to this one **without containing a loop**?

Python code:

```
luck = 0.3
tries = 200000000

getStrikes():
    strikes = 0
    for i in range(tries):
        if random.random() <= luck:
            strikes++;
    return strikes
```

Ok, sorry I've been spam editing the original post during the past 5 minutes. I will stop now since I've clarified what I wanted to ask based on the feedback I recieved.

Comment: It looks so much like Python, it may be easier to make it proper Python code.

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like to have peer-reviewed, your question belongs on [codereview.se]. If you have code that does not work, your question may be appropriate here, but you need to clearly explain what the problem is, include the relevant code, and ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Is there a specific language you want to implement this in?

Comment: Going with an expectation value of 3.5 for a fair-sided die, I'd say you can just `return 3.5 * die_rolls`, or even `return 700000000`. Or more generic, `return (1+die_sides)/2 * die_rolls`.

Comment: Unclear how the second part is an alternative to the first part: it's different code, with a different result. And both contain the same loop.

Comment: Python with numpy: (1) ```np.sum(np.random.randint(1,die_sides+1,size=die_rolls))``` (2) ```np.sum(np.where(np.random.randint(1,die_sides+1,size=die_rolls)==0)[0])``` (untested)

Comment: @Evert and add in a fudge factor `rand.float(-0.1, 0.1) * die_rolls` to make it look more authentic... ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no way to actually achieve what is asked.

Comment: Of course there is a way (recursive function), but he needs to post some constraints and show some effort.

Comment: @KenY-N: This is a math question. It's easy for those who know statistics. Me, I would have to look it up, and that's ideally what the OP should have done, some research. :)

Comment: @Ryan: You don't want to impose a requirement of no loop. That's just silly. Even a multiplication is a loop, at some level. Probably what you want is bounded computation about 7 or 8 orders of magnitude more efficient than what you have. Consider posting this on the statistics site instead, I would guess it's basics there.

Comment: I just read about the task = **more efficient calculation** (sry i missed it). Of course that's not really about removing the loop (as the fastest approaches will loop too). The python version above will be quite fast. The first two things to do to compute this more efficiently: (1) grab the random numbers in batches (opposed to sample & process, then sample & process; caching-effects + wasting less random-bits if supported by RNG-implementation) (2) compare/count in a vectorized way (again: caching & parallelization). Without external libraries, (2) might need some work.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - I should be able to crank the variable "tries" to 2 billion. Wouldn't the random.random() function call quite expensive? Also, the function exists as part of a single threaded server I'm working on. This function would be called several thousand times per second, that's why I'm  quite concerned about optimizing the performance of this function. I don't think looping quite cuts the cake here.

Comment: @Ryan A WE Wait... now i'm confused... i was sure, that this was just some toy-problem or school-task (as the dice-example didn't make any sense at all other than validating the RNG). It didn't help either, that you switched the problem in your question (first summing dice-rolls, than counting yes/no hits). So what exactly you need this for? If the current example is what you want (i don't know what for), Paul Hankin's answer is very powerful (but constrained to some specific problem-setting).

Comment: @RyanAWE: it would be nice if you didn't edit your question so much, I wrote a whole long answer that doesn't apply at all to the question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 3):

Your `strikes` is a random variable with the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). `scipy` has support for sampling from this distribution more efficiently than summing a huge number of [Bernouilli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

Here's an example:

```
from scipy.stats import binom

luck = 0.3
trials = 200000000
print binom(trials, luck).rvs()
```

Despite the large number of trials, this runs almost instantly.

Comment: Does binom() work fast when trials is low though (versus loop)?

Comment: @Ryan A WE If you understand the theory you could answer it yourself. **But in general:** why asking and not benchmarking it for yourself? As always when speeding-up something: benchmark it! We don't know your setting/numbers/cpu/memory...

Comment: @RyanAWE I don't know if it's fast enough for you. No doubt if `trials` is tiny (for example 1) then a loop will be faster. But if trials were tiny, I don't understand the intent of the question, which suggests that the code is too slow with the loop in it. Skimming the `binom` code, it looks like it runs in something like O(log(trials)) time, but it does quite a bit of work in each iteration.

Comment: @sascha I am working on a multiplayer game server on python webapp2, to be deployed to google cloud console using google app engine launcher. I don't know the cpu/memory stats of the server that will run the server code. Paul Hankin I'm worried that looping random.random() may cause a lot of unnecessary overhead which could be removed easily without a loop. Also, I've studied binom several years ago, but I forgot all about it.

Comment: @RyanAWE This is not about looping or not (the most optimized codes in the world are full of loops; look at any linear-algebra package). This is more about simulating bernoulli-trials or taking some math-shortcuts to obtain the statistics of the to-expected outcomes given some parameters. It all depends on what exactly you want to achieve. But given your question, this answer is very powerful (for huge trial-numbers).

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools for this in functional programming, like folds and list/generator comprehensions, but the most basic idea is recursion.

So, for instance, for getTotal():

```
getTotal(sides, dice):
    if dice == 0:
        return 0
    else
        return rand.int(sides) + getTotal(sides, dice - 1)
```

This function, sadly, will not work for your specific example, because the stack will overflow long before we get to the end. We solve that by making the function tail recursive, so you can use [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call_optimization) (not all languages use this feature, but virtually all functional languages do). That is accomplished by adding an accumulator variable that starts with 0:

```
getTotal(sides, dice, accumulator = 0):
    if dice == 0:
       return accumulator
    else
       return getTotal(sides, dice - 1, accumulator + rand.int(sides))
```

In this version of the function, the recursive call is a "tail call", which means that it is the very last thing the function does (that's not the case in the previous version, the addition is the last thing that happens, so it is not tail recursive). The `getSixes()` version can be done in the same way, except instead of just adding the dice roll to the accumulator, we add 1 if and only if the roll is a 6 to the accumulator.

However, this pattern is common enough that many languages have "shortcuts" for it, namely the [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). Since I don't want to invent a bunch of notation, I'm just going to write this next example in Python:

```
def getTotal(sides, dice):
    add = lambda x,y: x + y
    return reduce(add, (rand.int(sides) for _ in range(dice)))
```

`reduce` is python's name for a left-fold, and `add` is the function we're folding. The `(rand.int(sides) for _ in range(dice))` part is a generator that lazily (i.e. as we need them, not all at once in the beginning) generates your random number, specifially `dice` number of them.

Another trick of functional programming is to "filter" the values based on some boolean function. We can solve `getSixes()` that way:

```
def getSixes(sides, dice):
    condition = lambda x: x == 6
    return len(filter(condition, (rand.int(sides) for _ in range(dice))))
```

All of these ways have the same memory/speed characteristics of using a loop (that is, the same big-O characteristics), though using loops is generally a bit faster because there's less overhead.

Edit: this answer applies more to the version of your question previous to your edit, but the idea is very similar to your new version.

Edit 2: the original title was "how do you rewrite this problem without using a loop", which is what my answer applies to, how to do this without using loops. I didn't realize you wanted a mathematical formula, why my answer doesn't apply to at all.

Comment: It's sad to see, that you invested so much work into this, but missed what the OP was *actually asking* for, **which is not your fault**.

Comment: Yeah, that was real annoying.

Comment: yeah it's my fault, and i'm really sorry about that